# Keycloak: updating admin user with e-mail and name results in error

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to test the SMTP mail settings in my Keycloak configuration. The error I get is: Error! Logged in user does not have an e-mail.

For this to work, I have to set an e-mail and name for the Admin user, however: when I do that, it results in an error.[image]

Been researching this, but I am unable to find how to resolve this issue.

Any help on how to make this work, would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which keycloak version are you using?

Comment: I am using version: 15.0.2